# Prove: $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} C_i\binom{2(n-i)-1}{n-i} = \binom{2n}{n+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, catalan-numbers

I am working on the following problem:

Given that all of the legal paths (ones which do not cross over the line $y = x$) from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ must begin with a move to the right and end with a move upwards. And anytime the number of upward moves exceeds the number of rightward moves, the path becomes illegal. The solution seems to be the total number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ minus the total number of illegal paths.

Interestingly, I found that the number of illegal paths can be expressed by the formula:

$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} C_i\binom{2(n-i)-1}{n-i}$

Here, $C_i$ denotes the $i^{th}$ Catalan number. For instance, $C_0 = 1, C_1 = 1, C_2 = 2, C_3 = 5 ...$.

Also, the number of illegal paths is the second term in the  Catalan numbers: $\binom{2n}{n} - \binom{2n}{n+1}$, resulting in $\binom{2n}{n+1}$.

I am seeking a proof for:
$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} C_i\binom{2(n-i)-1}{n-i} = \binom{2n}{n+1}$

Any insights or methods to prove this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generating function approach. In the following we use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^i]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^i$ in a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^i](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{i}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}}&\color{blue}{\frac{1}{i+1}\binom{2i}{i}\binom{2n-2i-1}{n-i}}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i+1}\binom{2i}{i}\binom{2n-2i-1}{n-1-i}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}[z^i]\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4z}}[t^{n-1-i}](1+t)^{2n-2i-1}\tag{3}\\
> &=[t^{n-1}](1+t)^{2n-1}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left([z^i]\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4z}}\right)\left(\frac{t}{(1+t)^2}\right)^i\tag{4}\\
> &=[t^{n-1}](1+t)^{2n-1}\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-\frac{4t}{(1+t)^2}}}\tag{5}\\
> &=[t^{n-1}](1+t)^{2n-1}\frac{2}{1+\frac{1-t}{1+t}}\\
> &=[t^{n-1}](1+t)^{2n}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{2n}{n-1}}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (3) we apply the *coefficient of* operator according to (1) twice. Here we use the generating function $\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-4z}}$ of the *[Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)*. We also set the limit to $\infty$ without changing anything since we are adding zeros only.
- In (4) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply  the rule $[t^{p-q}]A(t)=[t^p]t^qA(t)$.
- In (5) we apply the substitution rule of the *coefficient of* operator with $z:=\frac{t}{(1+t)^2}$
  \begin{align*}
  A(t)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i t^i=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \left([z^i]A(z)\right)t^i
  \end{align*}
- In (6) we select the coefficient of $[t^{n-1}]$.

Comment: Upvoted. Check your email.